# collision detection in corona

Tags: lua, collision-detection, coronasdk

i am trying to move one of my physics body to a different xAxis on collision

```
local function onCollision(self,event)
            if event.other.name == "block" then
                if  (event.other.x - self.x) > 210 then
                    self:removeSelf()
                    self = nil
                    transition.cancel( event.other.move )
                    event.other:removeSelf()
                    event.other = nil
                    gameOver()
                else
                    print("else")
                    transition.cancel( event.other.move )
                    event.other.x = 1024
                    updateScore(1)
                end
            end
        end
        ball.collision = onCollision
        ball("collision",ball)
```

but it is saying

```
"Cannot translate an object before collision is resolved"
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a frame delay if you want to move colliding objects.

Replace

```
 event.other.x = 1024
```

with

```
local translateObject = function()  event.other.x = 1024 end
timer.performWithDelay(1,translateObject,1)
```

Comment: I did that too but what happens is,it first goes to else condition and coz of some delay if then goes back to if condition too as the collision is still taking place.Any other way to do that?

Comment: Hmm! Try giving `if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then return end` in your onCollision function.

Answer (score 0):

transition.to(ball, {x = object.x, y= object.x, time=0})

I found the answer to the question.